# How can I use random string in cypress test

Tags: javascript, random, cypress

How can I use random string in my cypress test so that whenever my gitlab-runner runs the code, the system will use difference strings like the Email and Phone number majorly.

I have my class created which i do call in my script.

here is the class that i created .

```
export class SignupPage{
   
 enterFirstname(firstname){
        cy.get('.grid-cols-2 > :nth-child(1) > .relative > .w-full').type (firstname)
    }
    enterlastname(lastname){
        cy.get('.grid-cols-2 > :nth-child(2) > .relative > .w-full').type(lastname)
        }
    
    enterEmail(email){
        cy.get('.space-y-3 > :nth-child(2) > .relative > .w-full').type(email)
      }
        enterBusinessName(businessName){
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .relative > .w-full').type(businessName)
        }
    enterBusinessType(){
    cy.get('#headlessui-listbox-button-1').click()
cy.get('#headlessui-listbox-option-4 > .font-normal').click()
}
    enterPhoneNumber(phoneNumber){
        cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .relative > .w-full').type(phoneNumber)
    }
    enterPassword(password){
        cy.get(':nth-child(6) > :nth-child(1) > .relative > .w-full').type(password)
  }
  clickAgreementBox(){
    cy.get('.h-4').click()

  }
        clickContinue(){
            cy.contains('Continue').click()
     
        }
        }
```

here is my test script

```
import { SignupPage } from "./pages/signup_page"


    const signupPage = new SignupPage()

describe('Registration', () => {
    it ('SoftPay registration page', () =>{
        cy.viewport(1280, 720)

        function makeid(length) {
            var result           = '';
            var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var charactersLength = characters.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
               result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
            }
            return result;
         }

        cy.visit('url.com/')
        cy.contains('Create Account').click()

        signupPage.enterFirstname('FirstName')
        signupPage.enterlastname('LastName')
        signupPage.enterEmail(makeid(6) + "@mailsac.com")
        signupPage.enterBusinessName('SoftPay TESTING')
        signupPage.enterBusinessType()
        signupPage.enterPhoneNumber(makeid(8)+ "82090808070")
        signupPage.enterPassword('********')
        signupPage.clickAgreementBox()
        signupPage.clickContinue()
        cy.end()
      })
      

})
```

this only work for the random email but not for the phone number

```
 function makeid(length) {
            var result           = '';
            var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var charactersLength = characters.length;
            for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
               result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
            }
            return result;
         }
```

Comment: Phone number usually contain only numbers, not the entire alphabet

Comment: Also, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113654/creating-a-random-string-in-cypress-and-passing-this-to-a-cy-command

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the easiest way is to use [faker.js](https://fakerjs.dev/api/person.html) library.

> Faker is a popular library that generates fake (but reasonable) data that can be used for things such as:
>
> - Unit Testing
> - Performance Testing
> - Building Demos
> - Working without a completed backend

For example

```js
const faker = require('faker')

export class SignupPage{
   
  enterFirstname() {
    const firstName = faker.person.firstName('female')
    cy.get('.grid-cols-2 > :nth-child(1) > .relative > .w-full').type(firstName)
  }

  enterlastname() {
    cy.get('.grid-cols-2 > :nth-child(2) > .relative > .w-full')
      .type(faker.person.lastName())
  }


 // and so on
```

See [Using Faker with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469172/using-faker-with-cypress) for another example.

Answer (score 1):

// In your Cypress commands file (usually cypress/support/commands.js)

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateRandomString', (length) => {


const charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
  let randomString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length);
    randomString += charset[randomIndex];
  }
  return randomString;
});
```

// In your test file

```
it('should use a random string', () => 
const randomString = Cypress.generateRandomString(10); // Generate a random string with a length of 10 characters
  cy.visit('https://example.com');
  cy.get('#inputField').type(randomString);
  // Perform other test actions
});
```

Comment: Custom commands don't work like that, your test will fail because `randomString` is not a string.